# How to replace values using apply() function.?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to update the values of column 'Age' using the `apply()` method.
I want to update the ages into 2 specific values. This is the function.

```
def new_age(a):
    if a<25:
       return 'pro'
    else:
       return 'notpro'
```

When I pass the apply function `df['Age'].apply(new_age)` it works fine but when i try to update the values of the "Age" column using `df['Age']=df['Age'].apply(new_age)` it returns NaN.
Can I get some help?
Edit: I tried the map() function. It did nothing better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

df['Age'] = np.where(df['Age'] < 25, 'pro', 'notpro')
```

This will be much, much faster than calling a function on each element.

Answer (score 1):

```
# imports, creataion of example dataframe
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([20,30,22,28],columns=['age'])
```

---

If want to stick with [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30282278/8565438) works for me:

```
df.loc[:, 'age'] = df.age.apply(new_age)
```

or, if you don't like [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.age[:] = df.age.apply(new_age)
```

Can you a [lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful/890188) as well:

```
df.age[:] = df.age.apply(lambda age: 'pro' if age<25 else 'notpro')
```